# CKEditor JavaScript error on IE8

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor version 3.6.1.
There is an error on IE8 when I put an empty row by "enter."
Here is an example:

```
writting test

writing test2
```

As you can see, there is an empty line between two sentences. When I click the empty row by mouse, I could not focus it to write something. To focus the empty row to write, I need to use my keyboard. Someone told me it's a JavaScript error on IE8. When I debugged it, I saw an error message like `setSize == undefined`. Does anyone know about this?

In addition, it's to hard to upgrade the CKEditor version, because I customized many codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to help you if you use old version of CKEditor, you have modified it and you haven't provided us any idea what you have changed and what error and where do you have.